# How to create a working VHDX in Azure CI Build Pipeline?

Tags: azure, winforms, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, msix

This question is related to [Azure MSIX Build and Package task only has Release and Debug configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895082/azure-msix-build-and-package-task-only-has-release-and-debug-configurations)

We have a WinForms project that has an MSIX installer. Manually, we can successfully create

1. An MSIXBUNDLE and deploy it to Kudu
2. An MSIX and deploy it to an Azure VM through a VHDX. We have manually convert the MSIX to a VHDX first

We are now trying to automate the build and release process to create the VHDX. However, we are getting a blank screen when the VHDX is mounted using a process that we have already validated. The only thing different is the build method (i.e., MSBuild versus VS Publish).

How do we create a working VHDX in Azure CI Build Pipeline?

Below is the YAML.

```
pool: 
  vmImage: windows-2019
  
variables:
- name: solution
  value: 'ProjectName.sln'
- name: buildPlatform
  value: 'x64'
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'development'
- name: major
  value: 1
- name: minor
  value: 0
- name: build
  value: 0
- name: revision
  value: $[counter('rev', 0)]  
- name: vhdxSize
  value: '200'
- group: 'legacy-pipeline'
- name: signingCertPwd
  value: $[variables.SigningCertPassword]
  
steps:
- powershell: |
     # Update appxmanifest. This must be done before the build.
     [xml]$manifest= get-content ".\ProjectName.MsixInstaller\Package.appxmanifest"
     $manifest.Package.Identity.Version = "$(major).$(minor).$(build).$(revision)"    
     $manifest.save("ProjectName.MsixInstaller/Package.appxmanifest")
  displayName: 'Version Package Manifest'
  
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.9.1'
    checkLatest: true
  
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: $(solution)
    feedsToUse: 'select'
  
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: ProjectName.MsixInstaller/ProjectName.MsixInstaller.wapproj
    platform: $(buildPlatform)
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
    msbuildArguments: '/p:OutputPath=NonPackagedApp
     /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly  /p:AppxBundle=Never /p:AppxPackageOutput=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ProjectName.msix /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false'
  displayName: 'Package the App'
  
- task: MsixSigning@1
  inputs:
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\**\*.msix*'
    certificate: 'Accumatch.DeveloperCodeSigningCert_TemporaryKey.pfx'
    passwordVariable: signingCertPwd
  
- task: AppInstallerFile@1
  inputs:
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ProjectName.msix'
    outputPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ProjectName.appinstaller'
    method: 'create'
    fileVersion: '1.0.0.0'
    uri: 'https://ProjectNamedemo.azurewebsites.net/ProjectName.appinstaller'
    mainItemUri: 'https://ProjectNamedemo.azurewebsites.net/ProjectName.msix'
    showPromptWhenUpdating: true
    updateBlocksActivation: true
  
- task: MsixAppAttach@1
  inputs:
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ProjectName.msix'
    vhdxOutputPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ProjectName.vhdx'
    vhdxSize: $(vhdxSize)
  
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is nothing wrong with the YAML. The problem was a delay in the virtual machine loading the VHDX. In other words, wait about 5 minutes once the VHDX is mounted before trying to run the application. I am leaving this here in case anyone else runs into this `issue`.